# Send information to another page and then send them to database

Tags: php

I have selected all information and when i click on button, information will sent to another page with hidden input:

```
    <?php
$id=$fgmembersite->UserID(); 

/* echo "$id"; */


$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'tablesite';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT tablesite.id_user,
                              tablesite.name,
                              tablesite.family,
                              tablesite.username,
                              tablesite.phone_number,
                              tablesite.email
                       FROM  $db_table",$con);
   $i = 1;

                       while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))

{?>
  <?php

echo "<form name=f1 id='form_$i' method='post' action=submit_action.php accept-charset='UTF-8'>\r\n";
echo'<div dir="rtl">';
echo "نام خدمت دهنده: "."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$amch["name"]." ".$amch["family"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."شماره تماس: ".$amch["phone_number"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."ایمیل: ".$amch["email"].'<br>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_customer" value="' . $amch["id_user"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $amch["name"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="family" value="' . $amch["family"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="phone_number" value="' . $amch["phone_number"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="' . $amch["email"] . '">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="choose" value="انتخاب مشتری"/>';echo'<hr/>';
echo'<hr/>';
echo'</div>';
echo "</form>\r\n";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

> in second page i call for picked information:

```
            <form name="form5" method="post" action="" >


<div dir="rtl">         
                    <?php
$username=$fgmembersite->UserNameOfUser();
   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_name= 'site';
   $db_table= 'job_list';
   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_pass = '';



$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT job_list.job_id,
                              job_list.job_name,
                              tablesite.username
                       FROM  $db_table
                       INNER JOIN relation
                       on job_list.job_id=relation.job_id
                       INNER JOIN tablesite
                       on relation.user_id=tablesite.id_user AND tablesite.username='$username'",$con);
echo'* خدمتی که ارائه داده اید: ','<br/>';                     
echo '<select name="job" dir="rtl">';

while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{ 
   echo '<option value="'.$amch['job_id'].'">'.$amch['job_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>'; ?><br/>
</div>      

<div dir="rtl"> 
<?php   

$user_id =$fgmembersite->UserID();   


            <label for='date' >* تاریخ عملیات:</label><br/>
            <?php

echo'<select dir="rtl" name="day">';
for($day=1;$day<=31;$day++)
            {


            echo '<option value="' . $day . '">' . $day . '</option>';

            }
echo'</select>';


echo'<select dir="rtl" name="month">';
for($month=1;$month<=12;$month++)
            {


            echo '<option value="' . $month . '">' . $month . '</option>';

            }
echo'</select>';

            echo'<select dir="rtl" name="year">';
            for($year=1388;$year<=1410;$year++)
            { 
            echo '<option value="' . $year . '">' . $year . '</option>';

            } 

echo'</select>';

?>          


            <br/>
            <label for='price' >* هزینه کار:</label><br/>
            <input type='text'  dir="rtl" name='price' id='price' value='' maxlength="50" placeholder="54000"/>تومان<br/>

        <label for='textaria' >توضیحات:</label><br/>
        <textarea name="textaria" cols="" rows=""></textarea><br/>
              <input name="submit" type="submit" value="ثبت عملیات" />

</div>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['choose']))
{
$id_customer =$_POST['id_customer'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$family=$_POST['family'];
$phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
echo "$name", " " , "$family", '<br/>' , "$phone_number", '<br/>' , "$email",'<br/>' , "$id_customer";
}

?>
        </form>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 

$date = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];

$id=$fgmembersite->UserID(); 

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'action';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);


$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
 $ins = "INSERT INTO $db_table
         (service_provider_id,customer_id,date,price,job_id,service_provider_comment)
         VALUES ('$id',
                 '$id_customer',
                 '$date',
                 '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['price']) . "',
                 '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['job']) . "',
                 '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['textaria']) . "')";
$saved=mysql_query($ins );
mysql_close($con); 

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("عملیات با موفقیت ثبت شد")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<script>window.location.href = "choose_user.php";</script>';


}
?>
```

I get this error:

> undefined index:id_user in..

Comment: which is the line causing this error??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju line of VALUES

Comment: So what _is_ the content of your `$_POST` variable when you receive the form?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju before of if(isset($_POST['submit'])) i can use my variables but when i use in that line show me undefined

Comment: @arkascha in second page i can fetch information but cant send!

Comment: What is the file name of your second file??

Comment: Looking at the notice you posted at the end of your question this tells me that you did _not_ receive `$_POST['id_user']`. So something is wrong with the received form values. That is why I asked. Because if it is clear that something is wrong with receiving, then how should sending work afterwards?

Comment: @arkascha can i send you my site with email for you?

Comment: @sajad Sorry, no. You posted a public question to the community here. Please provide the missing information to the question you asked so that people here can help.

Comment: @arkascha: i just updated my code by all thing i have

Comment: @sajad Sorry, but this code is pure chaos. I is unclear how the information flows, what is the purpose of that second file which appears to do several things at once. The `warning` or `notice` you post does not fit the code you posted. It does not get clear from the question what this is meant to do and what your actual issue is. It is impossible to answer to this.

Comment: @arkascha look in first page all users selected with a button for each of them, after choosing one buddy, the information sends to send page (user can see what he choosed) in third step, after user click on submit, the id_user have to send to database.

Comment: Please stop using mysql_* functions as these are obsolete starting with PHP version 5.5. Use mysqli_* or PDO functions instead.